# porblem with kinect.launch file in turtlebot bringup

Tags: kinect, turtlebot, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,

I want to run gmapping on turtlebot so i started with the basic turtlebot tutorials when i bringup the turtlebot and run the kincet.launch file the data published by kinect on /camera/depth/points is wrong also when i try to see the depth image using image view it's all black but when i run openni.launch file form the openni_launch package the kinect is publishing correct point cloud, ss there any problem with kinect.launch file in turtlebot_bringup I am using fuerte on ubuntu 12.04. this is my kinect.launch file

akhil@ubuntu:~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/turtlebot/turtlebot_bringup$ cat 2_kinect.launch

```
<rosparam command="load" />
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64226/porblem-with-kinect.launch-file-in-turtlebot-bringup/) by [akhil](https://answers.ros.org/users/2787/akhil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2013-06-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [akhil](https://answers.ros.org/users/2787/akhil/) on 2013-06-10**:
i just changed the value of  to false in kinect.laucnh file  and it worked but i don't know if this is the right way to solve this problem, any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Settint this value to false means that you won't have registered value and so that depth informations and color informations might not have the same coordinates. Hope that helps (even thought my answer comes late)

---

Originally posted by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) with karma: 318 on 2013-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0